# KendoUI grid how to preventDefault during Rowselect

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, preventdefault

I have a *selectable* **KendoGrid**

**Razor:**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<model>()
        .Selectable()
        .Events(events => events.Change("OnRowSelect"))
)
```

**jQuery:**

```
  function OnRowSelect(e){
    if(!condition) { //if specified condition is true, don't highlight/select the row
      e.preventDefault(); //my function passes the condition and trigger this line
    }
  }
```

What I wanted to do is to **cancel/prevent** the selection when it doesn't satisfy the condition. But in above code, when the code passes to `e.preventDefault()`, **it still selects the row**. It seems that the row was already selected by the time I called the `OnRowSelect` function. Is there an event that triggers before the **Kendo `Change`** event? Or am I just missing something?

How can I prevent it from selecting the row? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

No event is triggered before the `Change` event, but you can clear your selection :

```
function OnRowSelect(e){
    if(!condition) { 
        e.sender.clearSelection(); 
    }
}
```